# File sharing between windows 8.1 and ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: networking, ubuntu, windows-8.1, file-sharing

I have been trying all day to connect windows 8.1 and ubuntu 14.04.1 on my local network so I can share files between my two machines.

I have them hardwired (ethernet), have set up samba on ubuntu, both machines are using the same workgroup "WORKGROUP".

I was able to get windows 8.1 to access the various directories in ubuntu home (though in order to do so I had to allow guest access otherwise windows asks me for "credentials" I dont have and never created).

Now I am running into the same problem trying to access the windows 8.1 file system from ubuntu. If I try to access a shared folder like "photos" I get the error:

"Failed to mount windows share permission denied"

If I try to access a folder like "C" I get prompted for a username and password that I never set up. I have tried every username and password I have to no avail.

Shouldn't the username and password just be the username and password for the respective machines?

The two devices see each other on the network on both ends, but they seem to require some kind of username/password to connect to one another. Anyone know where I might find the info? I have been googling about this all day...

Comment: Have you read the relevant sections of this? Completely?https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba

Comment: No, I have been using ubuntu for 2 days. Super Noob. I will read docs, but could samba effect the windows machine's ability to read ubuntu's files? EDIT: Ah i see already it can. OK thanks I will read completely. Thanks for help. If I still dont get it I guess I will ask a less general question later